# jQuery get method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have these simple files in the head section of html like this----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/City.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? sensor=false"></script>
</head>
```

In the body section I have this simple method to open an alert box on click function:

```
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter the Project Details</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @if (ViewData.ContainsKey("City")) {
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, ViewData["City"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { style = "width:250px", @class = "DropDown1"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
                }
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">        
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var map;
                    $("#City").click(function() {
                        $.get("City.js", function () {
                            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
                            alert("Data : " + data);
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

I have my `city.js` file in a Scripts folder in the UI tier of my ASP.Net MVC application. Now I want to know why my JS code is not running.

Comment: still it's not working @Learner

Comment: You're also missing the closing bracket and brace on the `document.ready` block. You state that the `city.js` file is in the `scripts` folder. If that's the case, you've already included it in the `head`, so the AJAX call is redundant.

Comment: @Learner I have tried that too but failed

Comment: @Learner My application is multi tiered. The scripts folder is inside main startup project MvcPortal, I have other projects too attached to the solution file so what should i give the path ???

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In my original project, i have document.ready function

Comment: and `var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);` here `data` is `undefined` here try to change `$.get("City.js", function () {` to `$.get("/Scripts/City.js", function (data){` and remove refrence from head tag

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one closing tag }); .. just place it at the end

```
 <script type="text/javascript">        
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var map;
                    $("#City").click(function() {
                        $.get("City.js", function () {
                            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
                            alert("Data : " + data);
                        });  // closing for  $.get("City.js"
                    });// closing for   $("#City").click
}); // closing for (document).ready
            </script>
```

Comment: in my original project i have no syntatical error the code was complex so i have put here only that part which was not working i have all the ending tags at right places..... there is error in path getting i think or function is not recognizing which div is clicked that it

Comment: please post complete code.. #city is also not in code.

Comment: My code is minimal and everything required to put it running are there.....@Zohaib Waqar

Comment: you can check the error .. please run your application and the prss f12 and go to console . you will see error mesage there and let me know what is the error then i can suggest you better